# Conditional Expectation from generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions, conditional-expectation

Define the generating function $$f_n(\theta) = E (\theta^{Z_n}) = \sum_0^{\infty} \theta^k P(Z_n=k)$$ and suppose you wanted to compute the conditional expectation $$E (\theta^{Z_n} | Z_n \ne 0)$$

Then Williams 'Probability with Martingales' p11 says :
$$E (\theta^{Z_n} | Z_n \ne 0) = \frac{f_n(\theta) -f_n(0) }{1 - f_n(0)}$$

but i find that since $f_n(\theta) = E (\theta^{Z_n}) = \sum_0^{\infty} \theta^k P(Z_n=k) =  P(Z_n=0) + \sum_1^{\infty} \theta^k P(Z_n=k) $ then why not simply this? $$ E (\theta^{Z_n}|Z_n \ne 0) = \sum_1^{\infty} \theta^k P(Z_n=k) = f_n(\theta) - f_n(0) $$

Comment: it might be because the division by $1-f_n(0)$ isr required to reduce the sample space ie removes $Z_n=0$, still it would be great if someone could correct my fuzzy intuition :-)

Comment: You are conditioning (not intersecting) on the event $Z_n \neq 0$, therefore you must divide everything by $P(Z_n \neq 0) = 1-f_n(0)$.

Comment: Yes now i understand thank you very much for your time Sir